# PyQt5 Designer Fonts Between Linux & Windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I have been working through some tutorials using the pyqt5 designer. I am developing on windows but my end product runs on a linux raspberry pi. The font is quite different from one platform to another. On the raspberry PI is is much better. I could just adjust for this but is there a font style I could use that would be similar in both applications? What is the best practice for this. I would like the application to run on windows or linux and look the same.

Comment: The best practice is to honour the user's choice of fonts.

Comment: That font is much better *to you*. That's your taste, and your visual perception. You don't know if there are other fonts which might be "better", as there is no "best" font: the user might prefer a more decorative font for their system (I've seen lot people using "fancy" -and often awful and almost unreadable- fonts on their smartphones), or, more importantly, they might have some visual impairment for which they *need* a font that is different for its glyphs *and* size. The *only* acceptable exception is when a font is purely decorative and is not used for interactive elements.

Comment: I guess I should have worded my question better. I was asking which font I can use on the raspberry pi linux and the windows 10 desktop that will make an application that will look the same on both machines. Currently the linux has much better font.

Comment: Are you sure that the same font is available on both systems? There's no guarantee that the requested font will be the one that is actually used. You need to use [QFontInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html) (*not* QFont) to discover which one it is.

Comment: I  am having the same issue would like to have a font that is shared between windows and linux something everyone has like arial, but I do not see that as an option in QT Designer